# Issue with including encoded text string into twitter sharing button

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, urlencode

So I am attempting to use the twitter tweet button to tweet posts from a webpage. I am using the stock standard code straight from Twitter.

Assuming...

post_text = We've only got a "few characters" to explain things here

```
<a class="twittersocial" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Twitter', 'Share', '<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID)?>']); window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID))?>&text=<?php echo urlencode(substr(get_field('post_text'),0,86))?>...&via=twitterhandle&hashtags=newpost','Ratting','width=550,height=400,0,status=0,scrollbars=1');"href="javascript:void(0);" name="Share a quote on Twitter" title="Share a quote on Twitter" ></a>
```

Result in twitters pop up window:

We`&#039;`ve only got a `&quot;`few characters`&quot;` to explain things here... http://www.domain.com/newpost-x/ #newpost via @twitterhandle

What would be the best solution to ensuring the post isn't contaminated with the HTML character markup as seen here? I'm looking to make the solution as light as possible also as I'm replacing what was a very heavy social media plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

After checking the encoded URL string it seems that `'` from get_field was being represented as `&#039;` and subsequently encoded as `%26%23039%3B` (Encoded twice)

html_entity_decode was used to decode `&#039;` to `'` prior to encoding it back to `&#039;`

```
substr(html_entity_decode(get_field('post_text'), ENT_QUOTES),0,156)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

```
substr(strip_tags(get_field('quote_text')), 0, 86)
```

This will remove all html markup before doing the substring.

Comment: I forgot to include the backticks for the inline code. The post has been edited to show the actual result. it's the following characters that are displaying incorrectly and I've not been successful with strip_tags '"<>&

Comment: Can you post in your question exactly what `substr(get_field('quote_text'),0,86)` returns? (And put it in a code block so that the markdown doesn't mess it up.

Comment: I found the solution as per the edit above. The characters were encoded during get_field and then encoded again with url_encode.

Comment: @KhaledShaaban, don't edit your solution into your question. Post it is an answer, then accept it (and remove it from your question).

Comment: OK I've done that, I've got to wait 2 days to accept my own answer. Thanks for the help.